# Why does sysconfig.get_paths() contain local/ subdirectories on Ubuntu?

Tags: python, virtualenv

In a Python 2.7 virtualenv (virtualenv 1.8.2) on Ubuntu 12.04, `sysconfig.get_paths()` contains some paths with `local`, for example:

```
'platlib': '/home/me/prog/py27/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages',
```

The virtualenv is rooted at /home/me/prog/py27/. What is up with these paths?

Comment: I think this depends on the SO. Probably this is due to the fact that you use Ubuntu and thus the base and exec prefixes are set to use the local directories.
But I'm not sure.